# Query a reference to an object stored in a document mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, shell

I am wondering how exactly I would build query to filter based on the attributes of a stored document within a document using MongoDB.

Example:
My first collection is called Movies, it has a document as so:

```
_id: ObjectID("5d872b7f927f2538e4eefbf5")   
mvNumb : "1"
Director : ObjectID("5d8abd243372eb2850ad71e7")
```

The second collection is called Director, and the director has the following fields:

```
_id: ObjectID("5d8abd243372eb2850ad71e7")
Name : "Sam"
```

What I am trying to do, is filter al my movies based on their director name. An ideal query would look like :

```
db.Movies.Find({"Director.Name : "Sam"})
```

Comment: Can you let me know whether answer helped or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
db.directors.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      Name: "Sam"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "movies",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "Director",
      as: "movies"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      movies: 1
    }
  }
])
```

You can first get the target director with `Name` using `$match`. Then find the movies that director is affiliated with using `$lookup`, which is essentially a join-like operation, that fetches all such movies, and puts them under a `movies` field. Then just project those fields only.

Check on [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h_YZSiLQatw)